# Google calendar API insufficient Permissions issue for Event movement

Tags: google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I developed asp.net application to retrieve calendar events from google using google calendar api with oAuth2 authentication.
I am able to read the events from Calendar with any issue. 
But i am facing insufficient Permissions issue while moving events from primary calendar to another calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add scope for both read only and manage as mentioned below for asp.net static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar,CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };